# plyr::ddply error message: Error in class(output[[var]]) <- class(value) : attempt to set an attribute on NULL

Tags: r, plyr

This worked less than a month ago. Has something changed? (simple sample added):

adk47sample

```
PeakName Elevation
Marcy      5344
Marcy      5344
Marcy      5344
Marcy      5344
Marcy      5344
Marcy      5344
Marcy      5344
Algonquin      5114
Algonquin      5114
Algonquin      5114

> require(plyr)
Loading required package: plyr
> adk.need.fr.round.6 <- ddply(adk47sample, .(PeakName, Elevation),
+   summarize, needThese=if(length(PeakName) < 6) "needThis")

Error in class(output[[var]]) <- class(value) : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

For this simple example I expected:

```
> adk.need.fr.round.6
      PeakName     Elevation needThese
1     Algonquin      5114     needThis
```

Comment: Difficult to say without a reproducible example. Try adding an else clause to your `if`.

Comment: `plyr` has been updated recently ... reproducible example please http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ?

Answer (score 3):

It works for me with `plyr` version 1.8 if I give an `else` result of `character(0)` as @joran suggests (with `else NULL` it gives the same error):

```
adk.need.fr.round.6 <- ddply(adk47sample, 
.(PeakName, Elevation),summarize, 
  needThese=if(length(PeakName) < 6) "needThis" else character(0))
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks everyone. Adding "else" as suggested by joran and as implemented by Ben does the trick. So - I had been using the original code for two months now. I also used that "if" syntax on more serious data analyses I was doing about 5 months ago, so your collective help is greatly appreciated!!